# C++ templates working with objects *and* pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, c++-templates

I want to make a function template that will work with object instances and pointers as well.
This is important to me as this is the first step towards implementing a function that operates on a vector of elements as well as a vector of pointers to elements.

Here my code so far

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int num_ = 42;
    void print_num() const { std::cout << num_ << std::endl; }
};


template<typename T> void print_num(const T & obj)
{
    std::invoke(&T::print_num, obj);
}

template<typename T> void print_num_ptr(const T * const obj)
{
    std::invoke(&T::print_num, obj);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    Foo * foo_ptr = &foo;

    print_num(foo); // works
    print_num_ptr(foo_ptr); // works
    print_num(foo_ptr); // doesn't compile

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the compilation error I get

```
foo.cpp:14:18: error: type 'Foo *' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
    std::invoke(&T::print_num, obj);
                 ^
foo.cpp:30:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'print_num<Foo *>' requested here
    print_num(foo_ptr); // doesn't work
    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.
Cheers

=========

```
❯❯  g++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Do you know what template specializations are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: When `T` is `Foo*` then there is no `print_num` member function *on the pointer type*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the pointer-ness from the type using `std::remove_pointer_t`:

```
std::invoke(&std::remove_pointer_t<T>::print_num, obj);
```

If `T` isn't a pointer, `remove_pointer_t` will return the same type unchanged.

Or, if your only goal is to support `Foo::print_num()`, not `??::print_num()` in general, you can just use `&Foo::print_num`.

Comment: I didn't inspect it before answering and thought I had to dereference `*obj` :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, using `std::invoke` to automatically dereference pointers is weird. I'd probably do it explicitly if it was my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @HokyBlackCat!
That perfectly does the trick.

So now I can use my function with several types, instances and pointers as well.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

struct Foo
{
    int num_ = 42;
    void print_num() const { std::cout << num_ << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar
{
    int num_ = 17;
    void print_num() const { std::cout << num_ << std::endl; }
};


template<typename T>
concept HasPrintNumFn = requires(T a)
{
    { std::invoke(&std::remove_pointer_t<T>::print_num, a)} -> std::convertible_to<void>;
};

template<HasPrintNumFn T> void print_num(const T & obj)
{
    std::invoke(&std::remove_pointer_t<T>::print_num, obj);
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    Foo * foo_ptr = &foo;
    Bar * bar_ptr = &bar;

    print_num(foo);
    print_num(foo_ptr);
    print_num(bar);
    print_num(bar_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use the answer feature to thank a user. Given that you are the original poster, accepting the answer is the best way to show the solution provided has worked.

Comment: @BenA. Not "only" for thanking... As I'm sure you noticed, I also replied to several comments by posting the full answer showing the end result, which justifies the use of a more "complex" solution